# Split a string by some separaator

Tags: python-3.x, string

Let say I have below dummy code

```
import a_package as ap

calc = ap.func.func1()
```

So in my case `calc` is a function or method. However I want `python` to consider this as a string and split that based `.` and then return the last element i.e. return `func1`.

Is there any direct way to achieve the same?

Comment: Yes, use the `split` method.

Comment: `split` is a method only applicable to `string` object. So I think the expression `calc` needs to convert to a `string` object

Answer (score 0):

As the other reviewers noted, you will need to start with a string if you want to perform a string operation.  Assuming you have a way of getting a string in the form you showed, here are two examples of how to get the part of that string you are interested in:

```
import re

my_string = "ap.func.func1()"

# Should be sufficient for the use case you describe
my_split_string = s.split(".")
print(my_split_string[-1])

# More powerful (but more complex) if you have extended use cases
match = re.search(r"\.([^.]+)$", my_string)
print(match.group(1))
```

```
func1()
func1()
```

Comment: Thanks. But your suggested approach is failing in this case `import pandas as pd; dat = pd.DataFrame(); dat.split(".")`. As I said the expression `ap.func.func1()` needs to be converted to `string` before I apply `split` method - and I still dont know how can I do that